# Samsung Galaxy Note 4: greyscale mode disappeared after upgrading to marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery-life, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Today I've received the late Marshmallow 6.0.1 update. It has some unpleasant side effects:

1. Battery is draining fast
2. Greyscale mode has been removed
3. A very ugly grey bar is showing whenever I switch into Power Saver mode

Is there any workaround for these problems?

**Config:**

- Model: **N910c**
- Android Version: **6.0.1**
- Build Number: **MMB29K.N910CXXU2DPF6**
- Base Band Version: **N910CXXU1DPC1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still put your device in grayscale mode by enabling Developer options and changing the setting in simulate color space to monochromacy

Comment: It works, but it's kind of hacky! Do you know why they omitted that feature? Grayscale mode was about to reduce the battery usage, am I right? Or not? Does this simulation do the same as old Grayscale mode?

Comment: @STaefi No, switching the display to greyscale has no effect on the battery use. Maybe that's why they removed it.